# RAM clock is incorrect

Tags: boot, memory, speed

First time posting just built my first rig. I am having trouble though over clocking.

This is my MOBO and CPU

MSI Z87-G45 GAMING (MS-7821) 
Intel Core i5 4670K @ 3.40GHz

I have this RAM   [TEAM VULCAN](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820313418)

But U am having trouble setting the ram clock correctly. On speccy I am getting this result for my RAM
8.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 799MHz

I went into the MSI bios and attempted to change to DDR Clock to 2133MHz but My computer wont start.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything between 800mhz and 2133mhz by chance?  Link doesn't even work.

Comment: I tried 1600 and that also failed.

Comment: Also I fixed the link

Answer (score 1):

No speed much over 1066MHz is likely to work. This RAM is rated for an effective clock speed of 2133MHz which requires an actual clock speed of 1066MHz (because the is DDR RAM, the effective clock speed is always twice the actual clock speed). Make sure to raise the voltage to 1.65V, as the specifications require.